# JavaDoc in Android Studio not Recognize non English language

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I tried to Write javaDoc via my Mother Tongue Language **(Persian)** in Android Studio , but it's turned to Unknown Syntax. **Single Line Comment** and **Multi Line Commnet** don't have a problem.
Image : [image]

When I Generate JavaDoc it's Ok and doesn't have a problem like top image.
What can I do to Fix this Issue ?

Comment: not sure why :/ but it works fine for arabic language ... make sure that you have all the fonts installed for persian language in your android studio

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan tnx,i set the font "Tahoma" and every thing it's ok now